# startActivity doesn't work from a Fragment in HoneyComb

Tags: android

The onCreate() method is called but the new Activity never appears.  No errors are logged.

Follow up - There was no problem with calling startActivty() from a Fragment (we had a bug in the second Activity that caused it to exit immediately).

startActivity() from a Fragment works exactly like startActivty() from outside a Fragment.

Comment: Dude.. provide us some code.. only than we can help you..

Answer (score 5):

A fragment should not be calling `startActivity()`, IMHO. A fragment should be telling its activity to display something, and the activity should be deciding how to do that. In some devices, that might be launching another activity. In some devices, that might be by adding a fragment. That decision should be made at the activity level, as it is the activities that are deciding what fragments go in what activities, based upon screen size.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fragments/EU4You_6) where a click on an item in a `ListFragment` causes either a separate `DetailsFragment` to be updated (for `large`/`xlarge` screens) or pops a new activity (for normal screens).

Comment: The case is a an imageView that opens some Activity that might not even be in this application.  There is no reason why that second Activity has to be converted to a Fragment and no reason why the calling fragment should not be calling startActivty().  Fragment.startActivity() is part of the Fragment interface so clearly there is no reason to caterogically say the Fragments should not call startActivity().

Comment: @user275479: "The case is a an imageView that opens some Activity that might not even be in this application." -- IMHO, an `ImageView` should not be opening an `Activity` in *any* Android application, any more than a `TextView` should be performing an HTTP operation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bug in the second Activity that caused it to exit immediately.  So to answer my own question, there is no problem with calling startActivity from a Fragment.  It works exactly like calling startActivity from outside Fragment.