# Unable to call Activity from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am facing one little problem that I want to call Activity from FragmentActivity.
How can I do that?

This is my code.

(Edited)

```
class myClass Extends FragmentActivity
{


   OnCreate()
   {
        DirectionalViewPager pager = (DirectionalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setOrientation(DirectionalViewPager.VERTICAL);
        pager.setAdapter(new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        // I think problem is with this above line  in setting adapter because when I remove above three line it is not showing me error.. 
   }

   OnClick()
   {

      Intent intent = new Intent(myClass.this,nextClass.class);
      startActivity(intent);

   }

}

class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three",
            "Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine" };

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
08-25 17:37:04.230: W/dalvikvm(32535): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400cf760)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.chirag.teahouse/com.chirag.teahouse.TeaHouseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1012)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:507)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(DirectionalViewPager.java:454)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:8258)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1990)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1996)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1996)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:8241)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1603)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1164)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:470)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1114)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1184)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
08-25 17:37:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32535):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Post your error (from LogCat)

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427876/startactivity-doesnt-work-from-a-fragment-in-honeycomb

Comment: @YuviDroid For Error I am edited my que.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code

```
OnClick()
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),nextClass.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pager.setSaveEnabled(false) after setting adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted in your question doesn't have the correct syntax so I'm assuming you wrote it in here manually in order to not include sensitive code? ... anyway...

Your Logs show that your error isn't in starting a new Activity it's in pausing/saving your current Activity.

You can see from your Error:

```
at com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(DirectionalViewPager.java:454)
```

That your onSaveInstanceState() override method is what's failing.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try `pager.setSaveEnabled(false)` after setting adapter. It works for me.